# Is there any way to make Nautilus use different colors when showing list of files?

Tags: nautilus, colors

Is there any way to make Nautilus use different colors when showing list of files? Something similar to what ls does in console visually distinguishing archives, executable scripts etc?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Configuration for Coloured view as in terminal , but definitely File type based is available .

Go to **`Edit=>Preferences`** ,select in `List columns` as

[image]

which will enable you to view  File Type in **List View** under **MIME** type , (Application to open it) as

[image]

And in **TYPE** column , seen as

[image]

Or in **Icons view** , press `Ctrl+S` and type the file type you want to view as `*.jpg`  and `wall*` for file names to Highlight all the respective Files.

Comment: Thanks, I know I can see that column, the problem is that I normally use Compact view and color coding is in general easier to grasp than reading thru column.

Ctrl+S works in any mode and it's a good hint when you need selection.